# TLS and ASP.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssl

We have a ASP.NET web service that we want to upgrade, so that

1. It only works for connections made to it, using TLS 1.1+
2. All other connections are rejected/dropped.

While it's clear that the registry on the web server has to be updated to disable the older protocols, it is not clear as to how to upgrade the ASP.NET web service to TLS 1.1+

Are we good, if the application's DLLs are compiled against the .NET 4.5 framework? Or should we have to explicitly set the protocol in the web service code?

Comment: "....if the application's DLLs are compiled against the .NET 4.5 framework" ??? I must be missing something why are you asking about the .net framework version when are trying to implement an encryption protocol on your server?

Comment: Because it is my understanding that certain .NET framework versions don't support TLS1.1+. See article: https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/. I guess I'm also asking if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I do recall researching this while looking into implementing TLS.
"Apparently, the provider of the API I was trying to call disabled all other security protocols except for TLS 1.2. That was reason I was getting the error." 
The way I understand it is that the Framework comes into play on the Application that is making calls to the web API application secured by TLS:  "Well, that was because my application was using .NET 4.0. In .NET 4.0 default transport level security standard is TLS 1.1."

Comment: the TLS (protocol) transaction (encryption)  is occurring between the requesting application and the IIS hosting the (web) API. As such the target Framework of your WebService shouldn't come into play

Comment: If you have disabled protocols at the _server_ level, then _connections_ to it using those disabled protocols won't get through (IIS rejects it - it won't reach your application). The article you're referencing is when _you_ call an external API (e.g. via `HttpClient` or if memory serves `WebClient` pre 4.5) - e.g consuming Paypal APIs is restricted to `TLS 1.2`. Hth.

Comment: @DaniDev - Yes, it makes sense that the post was about a calling application. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of .Net Framework your app uses is relevant if any of the following is true:

- Directly using the System.Net APIs (for example, System.Net.Http.HttpClient and System.Net.Security.SslStream).
- Directly using WCF clients and services using the System.ServiceModel namespace.
- Using Azure Cloud Services Web and Worker roles to host and run your application. See the Azure Cloud Services section.

See *"Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework"*

Here's the link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls